# Technology to Prevent Multiple logins to the Same Computer

Tags: .net, windows, multiple-login

I re-asked this question here because the people at ServerFault [deemed that this is the appropriate place to ask this](https://serverfault.com/questions/54917/technology-to-prevent-multiple-logins-to-the-same-computer).

I am trying to prevent people from multiple login into one single computer and use my application *simultaneously*. **In other words I want to prevent it from running twice on the same computer, at the same time In any given time there shall be only one single user running my application**.

There is a reason for me to set the license usage that strict; my app serves a very specialized and very niche market. Hence, each copy costs around tens of thousands. If such multiple remote login tech gains prominence I would be put out of business in no time.

This is because I want to stop them from buying one license, install it on a machine, and use certain remote desktop technologies to do multiple user login. **I want to prevent them from violating the license agreement *technologically*, instead of law enforcement.**

Is there anyway that I can do in my application for this? Or is multiple login simultaneously is simply not possible?

I would prefer a non-dongle solution. My application runs on Windows only.

**Edit: To complicate the matter further, I allow simultaneous different version access ( my clients can install multiple version of the same software on one machine and fire them up at the same time). I just don't allow simultaneous remote login.**

Comment: Your application does not *own* the machine. Preventing two instances from running under a different username might be acceptable. In some cases, two instances for a single user as well. Preventing extra remote logins will only set your customers against you.

Comment: I allow remote login; it's just that I do not allow simultaneous remote login.

Comment: Thorarin: I have to disagree with you here. While I generally have a strong respect for the rights of the user; the OP does have a right to enforce his licensing constraints (however ridiculous; if you don't like it, don't buy it) within the extent of the law. And it's quite acceptable to use the approach I outline to ensure only one-instance is running.

Comment: I didn't want to make my mild rant my only contribution to this question, so I've included an example of how to use a system-wide mutex to prevent multiple application instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me clarify my standpoint a little. At least silky and I seem to be interpreting this in a different manner.

From what I understand, you are trying to prevent multiple users (or more instances of the same user) from logging in on *the machine* at the same time. In this you assume that the *sole purpose* of the machine is to run your application, which will generally not be the case.

Using silky's approach (system-wide mutex) to prevent multiple instances from running on the same machine is acceptable. Personally, I'd want to make sure there is no valid use case for a single user running two instances of your application to accomplish a task, before taking this approach.

See also this [programmer's pet peeve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423823/whats-your-favorite-programmer-ignorance-pet-peeve/426123#426123). Preventing multiple users from using the same machine falls into the same category ;)

As for your multiple version problem: choose a unique name for your system-wide mutex for every (major?) version of your application.

Basic example with a system-wide Mutex:

```
static class Program
{
    private static Mutex appMutex = new Mutex(false, "Global\\MyApp 1.0");

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        if (!appMutex.WaitOne(0))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Application is already running. Have a nice day.");
            return;
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

The `Global\` prefix makes the mutex shared over multiple terminal server sessions. Without it, it would only prevent a user from running two instances in the same session.

You should test this approach on an account that has limited rights, as it might be possible that restricted accounts cannot create such a mutex at all.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to prevent it from *running* twice on the same computer?

If that's the case the solution can be quite simple; take out a system-wide mutex or some similar approach, and then just check that and make sure it doesn't already exist. You could open a socket, or whatever, to achieve that.

Or do you want to somehow stop an account, other than the one that installed it, running it?

Comment: By mutex, are you talking about this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx

Comment: Yes. See the 'global\' mutex it talks about.

Comment: Your approach is perfectly acceptable, as it prevents two application instances from running. It does not prevent two users from being logged in on the same machine.